# How to get return type of template parameter method?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, return-type, decltype

I am trying to make a template class that expects a lambda as input, stores it, and also stores in a `vector` some elements of `type = return type` of the lambda.  But I don't know how to get that type, even though when an instance is built the lambda is known with also its return type.

I'd like the class to be constructed without giving template parameters (like `std::array a{1, 2, 3}`). I tried with `decltype(F::operator(double x))` but it doesn't work.

```cpp
#include <vector>

template<typename F>
struct Foo {
    using value_t = decltype(F::operator(double x))// <--- here I need to get the return type of the 
                                                 // call operator of F!
    Foo(const F& f) : _f(f), _vals(10, value_t{}), _has_vals(10, false) {}
    
    value_t operator()(int i) {
        if (_has_vals[i])
            return _vals[i];
        else {
            _has_vals[i] = true;
            _vals[i] = _f(i);
        }
    }
    
    F _f;
    std::vector<value_t> _vals;
    std::vector<bool> _has_vals;
};
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>    

int main() {
    Foo foo([](double x){ return 42; }); // <--- here I know that the lambda returns an int!
    std::cout << foo(3) << "\n";
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Maybe `decltype(std::declval<F>()(1.0))` ?

Comment: Unrelated: In `value_t Foo<F>::operator()(int i)` you need to check if `i<0 || i>9` or else there could be trouble. You also need to return a `value_t` in both branches. You currently have UB.

Comment: If the parameter type of the lambda is not default constructible, there is no way I suppose? Because there is no way to invoke the call operator on a default instance.

Comment: It happens that my lambda is called on types that are not default constructible. So I can't use decltype(declval<F>()(0.0)); because in my specific case 0.0 should be substituted by a default value.

Comment: Sorry, yea! @max66 I mean I can't do this, decltype(declval<F>()( NonDefaultConstructibleType() ));

Comment: `std::declval<NonDefaultConstructibleType>()`?

Comment: @lucmobz - `std::declval()` is available exactly for this sort of problems; as suggested by Ted Lyngmo, you can try with `decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<NonDefaultConstructibleType>()))`

Comment: thanks a lot, I need to review this stuff, it's resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) needs an actual call expression to get the return type, which you can't really reliably get from the type `F` (because the type `F` might not be default-constructible for example).

You must use [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to "create" an instance of `F` that you can then call.

Perhaps something like

```
using value_t = decltype(declval<F>()(0.0));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! The default value 0.0 is needed in order to identify what overload of the call operator to select, right? Even tho the lambda only has one?

Comment: @lucmobz It would help with overloads, if any, yes. But basically it's there to get an expression whose type is the return type, which we do by making up an example call.